# Inline variable in the Play framework 2.x Scala template

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

How to create an inline variable in the Play framework 2.x Scala template?
Path from the [Play's guide](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.1/ScalaTemplates) is not clear to me:

```
@defining(user.firstName + " " + user.lastName) { fullName =>
  <div>Hello @fullName</div>
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First you don't create a variable but a **value** meaning it's read only.

In your example you have created a value `fullName` which is accessible inside the curly brackets.

```
@defining("Farmor") { fullName =>
  <div>Hello @fullName</div>
}
```

Will print **Hello Farmor**

To define a value which is accessible globally in your template just embrace everything with your curly brackets.

E.g.

```
@defining("Value") { formId =>
  @main("Title") {
    @form(routes.Application.addPost, 'id -> formId) {
      @inputText(name = "content", required = true)
      <input type="submit" value="Create">
    }
  }
}
```

In the example you can use the value `formId` anywere.

Comment: ugly, convoluted! .... So much for all velocity/freemarker efforts to make views really clean and HTML-coder friendly. It seems that now the fashion is make html views a total mess  *sigh*

Comment: I agree! I dislike this syntax very very much.

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use the `@defining` syntax you can define a `reusable block` which will be evaluated every time you use it:

```scala
@fullName = @{
  user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
}

<div>Hello @fullName</div>
```

With this same syntax you can also pass arguments to the block:
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/samples/scala/computer-database/app/views/list.scala.html

Comment: Except a reusable block will be re-executed every time it is used, while the value of the defining block will only be computed once.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy, span your block with code from the sample, then you will can use `@fullName` variable which has value:

```
user.firstName + " " + user.lastName
```